# Javascript object. JSON.stringify and local storage

Tags: javascript, json, next.js, local-storage

Why is cart object saved as "cart" in the local storage? while it should have been a object. Because of that, the cart isnt displayed as it is supposed to be.

This happened after i deployed the website in vercel.
"cart" is string rather than an object,which is causing error.

The link of the site is : https://nepalwears.vercel.app/

@Yogi felt as the things i included wasnt enough. The object is created first in the addToCart method... When there is no items in the cart, the cart object is first created with the key of item code and with the values as qty, price, name, size, variant...

```
if (itemCode in cart) {
      newCart[itemCode].qty = cart[itemCode].qty + qty

    }
    else {
      newCart[itemCode] = { qty: 1, price, name, size, variant }
    }
```

After i deployed it in the vercel// the JSON.stringigy became "cart" in the local storage as shown in image..

This below is the code:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState({})

 const [subTotal, setSubTotal] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {

try {
  if (localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
    setCart(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")));   
    saveCart(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))); 
  }

} 
catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  localStorage.clear;
}
}, [])

 const saveCart = (myCart) => {

    localStorage.setItem("cart",JSON.stringify(myCart))
    let subt = 0;
    
    let keys = Object.keys(myCart)

    for (let index = 0; index < keys.length; index++) {
      subt += myCart[keys[index]].qty * myCart[keys[index]].price
    }
    setSubTotal(subt)
  }

  const addToCart = (itemCode, qty, price, name, size, variant) => {
    let newCart = cart;

    if (itemCode in cart) {
      newCart[itemCode].qty = cart[itemCode].qty + qty

    }
    else {
      newCart[itemCode] = { qty: 1, price, name, size, variant }
    }


    setCart(newCart);
    saveCart(newCart);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Voting to close because the question doe not provide enough detail to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Yogi, what more shall i add ? suggest me. Both the setCart and saveCart are mentioned there. and i explained my problem as good as i can. Instead of voting to close and trying to be know all,guide me. I accept i am a noobie.

Comment: If you clear local storage, does the `"cart"` value get added back? From going through the website I've only seen the `"cart"` value in local storage when clearing the cart from the UI ("Clear" button in the Cart) - can you share the code for that section?

Answer (score 0):

i opened the link in an incognito window and the problem doesn't appear. Has the problem occurred because i had the same object for both my local host and deployed site.

Answer (score -2):

In localStorage the value will be save as string even if it is an object. You need to parse it. Then you can access it as an object.

Comment: They are parsing it: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))` but the value shown in the debugger in the question is not the object (expressed as JSON) expected.